# Print complete SQL for all queries made by objection.js

Tags: objection.js

I'm looking for a way to capture the raw SQL for all the queries that the [Objection.js](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/) library executes *with the bindings interpolated into the SQL string.*

I realize that there's a [Knex event handler](http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-query) that I can take advantage of but the second argument to the `on('query', data)` is an object containing an SQL template with the bindings separate.

e.g.

```js
{
  sql: "select \"accounts\".* from \"accounts\" where \"id\" = ?",
  bindings: [1]
}
```

I'm wondering if the most elegant way to do this would be to use something like the [`.toString()`](http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-toString) method that exists on the QueryBuilder but I don't think a specific instance of a QueryBuilder is available in the callback. Ideally I don't reinvent the wheel and re-write Knex's interpolation method.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knex / objection.js does not provide any methods that can securely do the interpolation. `.toString()` can produce invalid results in some cases and they can be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

If it is only for debugging purposes looking how `.toQuery()` is implemented helps. https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/e37aeaa31c8ef9c1b07d2e4d3ec6607e557d800d/lib/interface.js#L12

```
knex.client._formatQuery(sql, bindings, tz)
```

It is not a public API though so it is not guaranteed to be the same even between patch versions of knex.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the heads regarding the pitfalls. I'm only using this for debugging purposes. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [`.toKnexQuery()` function](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/other-methods.html#toknexquery) to pull out the underlying knex query builder and gain access to [`.toSQL()`](https://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-toSQL) and `.toQuery()`.

I tested and verified the following example using version 2 of Objection. I couldn't find `.toKnexQuery()` in the [version 1 docs](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/blob/v1/doc/api/query-builder/other-methods.md) and therefore can't verify it will work with earlier versions of Objection.

```js
// Users.js
const { Model } = require('objection')

class Users extends Model {
  static get tableName() { return 'users' }
  // Insert jsonSchema, relationMappings, etc. here
}

module.exports = Users
```

```js
const Users = require('./path/to/Users')

const builder = Users.query()
  .findById(1)
  .toKnexQuery()

console.log(builder.toQuery())
// "select `users`.* from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1"

console.log(builder.toSQL())
// {
//   method: 'select',
//   bindings: [ 1 ],
//   sql: 'select `users`.* from `users` where `users`.`id` = ?'
// }
```

---

It should probably be reiterated that in addition to `.toString()`, `.toQuery()` can also be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (see [here](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3377)).

A more "responsible" way to modify the query *might* be something like this (with MySQL):

```js
const { sql, bindings } = Users.query()
  .insert({ id: 1 })
  .toKnexQuery()
  .toSQL()
  .toNative()

Users.knex().raw(`${sql} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE foo = ?`, [...bindings, 'bar'])
```

Comment: This is a useful answer, but did not work regarding the "*all* queries" consideration. I am using the `withGraphFetched()` method to get related data and these techniques did not print out the queries for the "subsequent" queries (not sure what to call them... Objection.js doesn't use joins with `withGraphFetched` but runs follow-up queries).